Selectively disable parts of Visual Studio XML comment completion?
As I type my comments, Visual Studio very frequently but apparently randomly expands a word to various tags.
For example, I type 'get' and it converts it to <see langword="get"/>. I can't tell why it expands sometimes but not others for the same word.
How do I disable this 'feature'?

My guess is that completion is appearing, and that "space" is committing an item from the completion list. Seems like a bug. As a workaround, you can configure which keys commit completion, however that'll impact all code in the editor, not just XML doc comments. You should file this problem at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio

If you want to turn off this automatic expansion feature, you can do this by going to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense and unchecking Show completion list after a character is typed. Please note that this will turn off the IntelliSense auto-completion feature. If you only want to know where VS has a specific option to turn off the automatic expansion feature, it should be noted that VS does not currently have a separate module for this.

@Digiproc I'd like to ask if the solution in this answer is useful, or if you found another solution?
